# ModalDrawer don't cover NavigationBottom in Android JetPackCompose

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I wrote code that drawer show/hide when button tap in AppBar.
It is success for drawer to show or hide, but modalDrawer don't cover BottomNavigation.

How can I fix code to cover BottomNavigation?

this problem image is [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g2dGv.png)

my writing code is below.(the code compose AppBar and MaterialDrawer and BottomNavigation)

```
@Composable
    fun MainScreen() {
        val navController = rememberNavController()
        val puppi by viewModel.uiState.collectAsState()
        val drawerState = rememberDrawerState(DrawerValue.Closed)
        val scope = rememberCoroutineScope()

        val submit = {
            scope.launch {
                drawerState.open()
            }
            Unit
        }

        Column(
            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
            verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Bottom
        ) {
            NavHost(
                navController = navController,
                startDestination = NavigationItem.HOME.route,
                modifier = Modifier
                    .weight(1f)
            ) {
                composable(NavigationItem.HOME.route) {
                    ModalDrawer(
                        drawerState = drawerState,
                        drawerContent = { DrawerView(drawerState) },
                        content = {
                            Column(
                                modifier = Modifier
                                    .fillMaxSize()
                                    .padding(0.dp)
                            ) {
                                TopAppBar(
                                    title = { Text(text = "Test") },
                                    navigationIcon = {
                                        IconButton(onClick = { /* do something */ }) {
                                            Icon(Icons.Filled.Menu, contentDescription = "Open drawer")
                                        }
                                    },
                                    backgroundColor = Color.White,
                                    actions = {
                                        IconButton(onClick = { /* do something */ }) {
                                            Icon(Icons.Filled.Share, contentDescription = "Share text")
                                        }
                                    }
                                )
                                ListFormFirst(puppi.user)
                            }
                        }
                    )
                }
                composable(NavigationItem.CRYPT.route) {

                }
            }

            BottomNavigation(backgroundColor = Color.White) {
                val backStack by navController.currentBackStackEntryAsState()
                val current = backStack?.destination?.route

                NavigationItem.values().forEach { item ->
                    BottomNavigationItem(
                        selected = current == item.route,
                        onClick = {
                            navController.navigate(item.route) {
                                // no back stacks. 0 is the root navigation
                                popUpTo(id = 0) {
                                    saveState = true
                                }
                                launchSingleTop = true
                                restoreState = true
                            }
                        },
                        icon = { Icon(item.icon, null) },
                        label = {
                            Text(
                                text = item.label,
                                maxLines = 1
                            )
                        },
                    )
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `ModalDrawer` is inside your `NavHost`, so it will only cover the content inside your `NavHost`. If you want it cover everything, then the `ModalDrawer` needs to be outside of your `Column` that contains both your `NavHost` and the `BottomNavigation`:

```
ModalDrawer(
    drawerState = drawerState,
    drawerContent = { DrawerView(drawerState) },
) {
    Column(
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
        verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Bottom
    ) {
        NavHost(
            navController = navController,
            startDestination = NavigationItem.HOME.route,
            modifier = Modifier
                .weight(1f)
        ) {
            composable(NavigationItem.HOME.route) {
                Column(
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .fillMaxSize()
                        .padding(0.dp)
                ) {
                    TopAppBar(
                        // ...
                    )
                    ListFormFirst(puppi.user)
                }
            }
            composable(NavigationItem.CRYPT.route) {

            }
        }

        BottomNavigation(backgroundColor = Color.White) {
            // ...
        }
    }
}
```

If you only want the drawer accessible on certain destinations, you'd use the same technique as your `BottomNavigation` - using the `currentBackStackEntryAsState` to determine whether to set the `gesturesEnabled` property on the `ModalDrawer` to true (i.e., users can interact with the drawer) or false (i.e., they cannot interact with the drawer).

This concept of a `ModalDrawer` plus a `BottomNavigationBar` is typically done using a [Scaffold](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/material/package-summary#Scaffold(androidx.compose.ui.Modifier,androidx.compose.material.ScaffoldState,kotlin.Function0,kotlin.Function0,kotlin.Function1,kotlin.Function0,androidx.compose.material.FabPosition,kotlin.Boolean,kotlin.Function1,kotlin.Boolean,androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Shape,androidx.compose.ui.unit.Dp,androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Color,androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Color,androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Color,androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Color,androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Color,kotlin.Function1)), which does all of these things together, taking care of positioning the content above the `bottomBar` content by giving your content the correct `PaddingValues`.

```
val scaffoldState = rememberScaffoldState()
// Get the DrawerState from the ScaffoldState
val drawerState = scaffoldState.drawerState
Scaffold(
    scaffoldState = scaffoldState,
    drawerContent = { DrawerView(drawerState) },
    bottomBar = {
        BottomNavigation(backgroundColor = Color.White) {
            // ...
        }
    }
) { innerPadding ->
    NavHost(
        navController = navController,
        startDestination = NavigationItem.HOME.route,
        modifier = Modifier.padding(innerPadding)
    ) {
        composable(NavigationItem.HOME.route) {
            // ...
        }
        composable(NavigationItem.CRYPT.route) {
            // ...
        }
    }
}
```